# Параллельный вызов метода C# WPF

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня есть метод, который принимает в качестве параметров 2 строки и возвращает одну строку.

```
public string func(string one, string two)
{
                string result = one + two;
                return result;
}
```

У меня этот метод вызывается каждый раз, когда меняется значение в текстовом поле

```
    private void textBoxOriginal_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        OutputText = func("StringOne", "StringTwo");
}
```

Изменение происходит довольно часто, из-за этого есть небольшие подвисания. 
Как можно это решить?
Пытался так:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

            });
```

Но вылетает с такой ошибкой: "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."
Спасибо 
UPD при написании текста в textBoxOriginal вызываю TranslateText, который должен после выполнения некоторых операций textBoxResult присвоить результат.

```
async private void textBoxOriginal_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBoxResult.Text = await Task.Run(() => AdditionStrings(this.textBoxOriginal.Text, "Plus This"));
        }
public void AdditionStrings(string one, string two)
{
    string result = one+two;
    ...
    this.textBoxResult.Text = result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте примерно так. Интерфейс по крайней мере не будет заблокирован.

```
public string AdditionStrings(string one, string two)
{
    string result = one + two;

    //это для задержки, типа долго вычисляем...
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Wait();

    return result;
}

private async void buttonOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = this.textBoxOriginal.Text;
    this.textBoxResult.Text = await Task.Run(() => AdditionStrings(text, "Два"));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Одна проблема, как говорил ранее у меня есть два текстбокса на форме. При изменении одного, нужно вызывать AdditionStrings          this.textBoxResult.Text = await Task.Run(() => AdditionStrings(textBoxOriginal.Text, "ru|en")); в 
Ругается на textBoxOriginal - "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток." Если передавать параметры вида AdditionStrings("Один", "Два"), то все нормально. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: @Xom9ik чего-то я недопонял. Добавьте в вопрос ниже уточнение с кодом.

Comment: добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Xom9ik добавил в ответ

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, то что мне было нужно, теперь интерфейс не тормозит)

Comment: OK. Пожалуйста.

Comment: @Xom9ik вы все таки найдите время посмотреть это [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9qcKV4j75U&list=PLWCoo5SF-qAMDIAqikhB2hvIytrMiR5TC&index=19) и далее про многопоточность.